# How to make local call on apollo graphql?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I am using `apollo graphql` in a nodejs application. It is not a server/client mode. Everything is running in one application so there is no `http` required.

How can I implement graphql in one application? 
I have defined `schema`, `resolvers`. But I don't know how I can make a in memory graphql server? And how can I query the server without using http link?

Graphql spec doesn't mention anything about implementation which means I can use different transports like `http`, `websocket` etc. In my case, I just want to use a local transport without network.

Comment: Even if both your server is serving the `GraphQL` endpoint/API **and** it serves your client-side application, you **still** need a network request to communicate between the two, there's no other way to go about this.

Comment: How about I don't use the `term` server/client. I just want to make use of graphql schema and resolvers pattern to implement a single desktop application.

Comment: Again, **you need a network request to communicate between a client and a server**, there's just no other way to go about this. I understand that both are being served from the same server, but there's no such thing as "local transport without network."

Comment: socket means server, too ;) you still need some server for parsing queries, invoke your resolvers and return data/response ... write it all yourself if you want